# Why does coalescing make this query quicker?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, null, coalesce

I have the following query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    `table1`.*
FROM 
    `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table2.id = table1.table2_id
WHERE 
    (`table2`.`date_assigned` >= '2015-06-21')
    AND (
        `attempt_1_date`IS NOT NULL
        OR `attempt_2_date`IS NOT NULL
        OR `attempt_3_date`IS NOT NULL
        )
    AND (
        `attempt_1_date` >= '2015-08-16'
        OR `attempt_2_date` >= '2015-08-16'
        OR `attempt_3_date` >= '2015-08-16'
        )
    AND (
        `callback_date`IS NULL
        AND `callback_by_account_id`IS NULL
        AND `callback_result`IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        (
            `attempt_1_result` NOT IN ('complete,incorrect,decline,prospecting')
            OR `attempt_1_result` IS NULL
            )
        AND (
            `attempt_2_result` NOT IN ('complete,incorrect,decline,prospecting')
            OR `attempt_2_result` IS NULL
            )
        AND (
            `attempt_3_result` NOT IN ('complete,incorrect,decline,prospecting')
            OR `attempt_3_result` IS NULL
            )
        )

    #AND (`table2`.`date_completed` IS NULL)
    AND (COALESCE(`table2`.`date_completed`, '') = '')
```

If I coalesce the `date_completed` field first, my Database program says the query comes back in 0.000 seconds, yet if I used the above (commented out) line, just checking IS NULL, it takes just over 10 seconds. Both only return the same 5 results.

`table1` has 24 columns, and ~171,000 rows, and `table2` has 172 columns*, and 1.7 million rows. In 1.4 million of those rows, `date_completed` is null.

If you need any more information, just let me know.

Few more details I was advised to include:

```
MySQL version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log
```

Explain outputs:

**Using COALESCE**

```
`id`, `select_type`, `table`, `type`, `possible_keys`, `key`, `key_len`, `ref`, `rows`, `Extra`
1, 'SIMPLE', 'table1', 'index_merge', 'table2_id,attempt_1_date,attempt_1_result,attempt_2_date,attempt_2_result,attempt_3_date,attempt_3_result', 'attempt_1_date,attempt_2_date,attempt_3_date', '9,9,9', NULL, 8, 'Using sort_union(attempt_1_date,attempt_2_date,attempt_3_date); Using where'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'table2', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,ind_table2_date_assigned', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'database.table1.table2_id', 1, 'Using where'
```

**Using IS NULL**

```
`id`, `select_type`, `table`, `type`, `possible_keys`, `key`, `key_len`, `ref`, `rows`, `Extra`
1, 'SIMPLE', 'table2', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,ind_table2_date_completed,ind_table2_date_assigned', 'ind_table2_date_completed', '9', 'const', 10, 'Using where'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'table1', 'ref', 'table2_id,attempt_1_date,attempt_1_result,attempt_2_date,attempt_2_result,attempt_3_date,attempt_3_result', 'table2_id', '5', 'database.table2.id', 1, 'Using where'
```

Few more notes.

- date_completed is type DATETIME
- There are no entries where date_completed = ''

<sub><sup>*120 of those rows relate to 60 questions, in the format `question_x_score`, and `question_x_value`</sup></sub>

Comment: The "IS NULL" variant uses index `ind_customer_surveys_date_completed` and expects to get only 10 rows, but you say 1.4M has NULL for that column.. So it seems to me statistics on that index are really bad. You can check with `show index from customer_surveys;` called before and after `analyze table customer_surveys` and look for `cardinality` column.

Answer (score 1):

The timings could be bogus because of caching.  You probably have the Query cache on.  Try again, but with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...;`

Recommend you add a new possibility to the ENUM behind this:

```
`attempt_1_result` NOT IN ('complete,incorrect,decline,prospecting')
        OR `attempt_1_result` IS NULL
```

That way you could avoid the `NULL` test and the `OR`.

```
AND `table2`.`date_assigned` >= '2015-06-21'
AND `table2`.`date_completed` IS NULL
```

would benefit from `INDEX(date_assigned, date_completed)` (in either order).

Why do you have `LEFT JOIN`?  It seems like `JOIN` would give you the same result?

Why do you even mention `table2`?  You are not fetching anything from it.

Comment: Oops.  OK, my next guess is that `index_merge` is being especially inefficient.  (I have seen such before.)  It's presence in the `EXPLAIN` hinted that a "composite" index was called for.  (I gave you that suggestion.)